# amazon php sdk and flourishlib autoloader s3client could not be loaded

Tags: php, amazon-s3, spl-autoload-register, flourishlib

I am attempting to upload a file to s3 using php 5.3.3. I am using the Amazon PHP sdk and using the autoloader. The problem is that the autoloader for AWS is not loading the classes correctly and we are getting a exception when loading S3. Our server structure looks like this:

->public (www document root)

->lib

->->aws

So our upload code is located in /public/ and our AWS library is located at /lib/aws/ so to get from public to lib we do /../lib/aws/.

Here is what the upload.php code looks like in the public folder which initiates the amazon upload:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../lib/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

echo 'creating...';
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => '****',
    'secret' => '******'
));
```

It successfully works and prints the echo 'creating...' output and then we get an error.

Here is what the exception looks like:

```
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     creating...  
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     ( Exception Object
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [message:protected] => The class S3Client could not be loaded
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [string:Exception:private] =>
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [code:protected] => 0
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [file:protected] => /public/upload.php
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [line:protected] => 26
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [trace:Exception:private] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC         (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC             [0] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [function] => __autoload
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [args] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                             [0] => S3Client
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC             [1] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [file] => /public/upload.php
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [line] => 15
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [function] => spl_autoload_call
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [args] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                             [0] => S3Client
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC             [2] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [file] => /public/upload.php
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [line] => 408
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [args] => Array
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         (
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                             [0] => /public/upload.php
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                         )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                     [function] => include
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC                 )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC         )
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC     [previous:Exception:private] =>
2014-04-12 19:46:40 UTC )
```

We are using the latest version of AWS from:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

We are using PHP 5.3.3 and also the flourishlib:
http://flourishlib.com/

That also has a flourishlib autoload function which looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    // Customize this to your root Flourish directory
    $flourish_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../lib/flourishlib/';

    $file = $flourish_root . $class_name . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
        return;
    }

    throw new Exception('The class ' . $class_name . ' could not be loaded');
}
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

I think what is happening is the flurishlib autoload function is trying to load the amazon classes and its causing a error.

How can I make amazon use the correct autoload function?

Answer (score 0):

Strike that, reverse. Nobody should *ever* still be using the `__autoload()` function. This was deprecated many years ago in favor of the stackable `spl_autoload_register()` function.

From the code snippet you posted, FlourishLib is doing the *wrong* thing by having a function called `__autoload()` at all.

Comment: Well the __autoload function is not being registered automatically that is why at the bottom we have the spl_autoload_register function. Calling it a __autoload makes no difference I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem here is that you are not reference the `S3Client` class properly. In no place above did I see you use the fully-qualified class name. **Try adding**

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

---

It also looks like you don't need the other two `use` statements (at least in the code you provided), because you are not actually using either of those two classes. You should be able to **remove**

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
```

And yes, I agree with Ryan that `__autoload` is bad, but it appears you are handling it correctly by registering with the spl autoload chain.